# Can i use multiple viewModel in same view in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Is it possible to use multiple view model in same view?

I was trying to use a viewmodel using @model attribute

But i am stuck if i can use a second viewModel, where i put the second one?

Comment: You can only have one `@model` declaration in the view (your view model can contain properties from multiple models)

Comment: The question could mean any number of things - can you use a composite ViewModel? Or can you use viewmodels interchangeably? Yes to both

Comment: "Multiple View Models" in its simplest form is *one* ViewModel with multiple properties. Those properties can be complex objects themselves

Comment: those question are related to models and my question is specific to viewmodel

Comment: Can you use multiple models in place of each other? Yes again, as long as they inherit the same interface. You could also use dynamic typing. The view would work as long as all viewmodel instances have the same methods, properties

Comment: @SmartestVEGA no they don't. They are specific to *viewmodels*. Yes, you can have composite view models. Yes, you can have interchangeable viewmodels. You can also use an *array* as a ViewModel, allowing you to use multiple instances of the same ViewModel

Answer (score 5):

You can't send two view models in the same View.

As a quick workaround, you can create another class that wraps all the models you want to send in the view. By this way, you will benefit from a strongly typed view.

```
  public class Foo
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class Bar
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class FooBar
  {
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
  }
```

Inside your action method:

```
  var foo = new Foo
  {
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Foo"
  };

  var bar = new Bar
  {
    ID = 2,
    Name = "Bar"
  };

  var fooBar = new FooBar
  {
    Foo = foo,
    Bar = bar
  };

  return View(fooBar);
```

Comment: can show as a code example for this?

Comment: That's not a "quick workaround", that's how ViewModels work and the basis for composability and partial views

Comment: I have edited my answer with a example.

Comment: BTW who downvoted the answer that could demonstrate the more advanced MVC features eg how to use partial views?